# How to get list of tables in excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have an Excel Workbook that has several worksheets in it. The tables in the worksheets have been assigned names using the Name Manager in Excel. Is there a way to get a list of these table names?

Comment: I need the name of the tables in sheet, not the sheet names

Comment: You mean the table name inside each subsheet?

Comment: In my case there is an excel file which has a sheet named "Reel". In this sheet there are several tables, each table having a unique name. I need to get the list of these unique table names and other attributes like dimension(rows and cols).

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of your tables?